# Weird Tikz positioning behaviour; calc, \graph, subgraph

Tags: tikz-pgf, graphs, tikz-calc

I have the following code. It behaves as expected when only one middle node is drawn; however, when both are there the result is surprising. Why is that? How can I fix it?

```
\documentclass[border=2mm]{standalone}

\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{ calc }
\usetikzlibrary{ graphs, graphs.standard }

\begin{document}
    \begin{tikzpicture}
        \graph[ nodes = { fill = blue }, empty nodes ]{
            subgraph C_n [n = 8, clockwise, radius = 2cm];
            1 -- 9 [at = { ($(1) ! 0.5 ! (6)$) }] -- 6;
            2 -- A [at = { ($(2) ! 0.5 ! (5)$) }] -- 5;
        };
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image] [image] [image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you wan to position nodes “by hand” you have to “switch off” the whole placement mechanism with `no placement`. You can do this locally.

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=7pt]{standalone}
\usetikzlibrary{calc, graphs, graphs.standard}

\begin{document}
  \begin{tikzpicture}
    \graph[nodes={fill=blue}, empty nodes]{
      subgraph C_n [n=8, clockwise, radius=2cm];
      {[no placement] % <----- switch off auto placement
        1 -- 9 [at={($(1)!0.5!(6)$)}] -- 6;
        2 -- A [at={($(2)!0.5!(5)$)}] -- 5;
      }
    };
  \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: What is a good way to achieve what I want using \graph? Let's say I want the node to be at 25% distance from the first node. What about the middle as it is the case here?

Comment: Your question is not clear for me. Kpym's answer seems to solve the issue, doesn't it? Everything is done into the `\graph` environment.

Comment: Yes, it almost does solve it. The thing is that I have a feeling that this way of writing it was not intended by the authors of \graph, it is a workaournd.  It is somewhat "out of place," "not intuitive." I was waiting for @Kpym to respond to see how he would have done it instead. Also an explanation of what this internal placement mechanism is would be nice. Nevertheless, if my feeling is not true I will designate this solution as a correct answer. I will give it few more days.

Answer (score 1):

While I can't figure out why this library behaves like this, I'll give a solution that subvert the issue and doesn't require any additional library.

[image: simple graph]

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=3.14mm]{standalone}

\begin{document}
    \begin{tikzpicture}[every node/.style={draw,fill=blue,inner sep=1.5mm}]
        \foreach \i in {1,...,8} \node (\i) at (135-\i*45:2) {};
        \foreach \j [count =\i from 1] in {2,3,...,8,1} \draw (\i) -- (\j);
        
        \draw (1) -- (6) node[midway] (A) {};
        \draw (2) -- (5) node[midway] (B) {};
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Thank you @sabGlav for your alternative solution. I am mainly looking for understanding so that I can better utilize \graph and calc in my more complicated graphs.

Comment: That's no problem. Actually, I'd like to understand this strange behaviour too, because if you add a third line like yours, it's even more weird. It could be a bug and would be reported, if so.